# BIRT part of datasource as parameter

Tags: parameters, datasource, birt

I have a birt report with a database url `jdbc:postgresql://randomHost/randomName_2011`
I have databases with exactly the same structure for other years. Only difference in the url is the year number.

Would it be possible to give the year number as a parameter when opening the report?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to set database url with "Property Binding".

- Open your datasource definition
- Go to "Property Binding"
- Open Expression Builder for "JDBC Driver URL" field (button "f(x)" right of an input field)
- Enter expression

  ```
  "jdbc:postgresql://randomHost/randomName_" + params["year"].value
  ```